# Can white balance be changed in scene modes with the Nikon Coolpix L23?

Tags: nikon, white-balance, scene-modes

Can we change white balance in scene modes (portrait, landscape, etc....) of the [Nikon Coolpix L23](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/coolpix/life/l23/)?

Answer (score 1):

I know with the D90, you cannot adjust white balance, change the metering mode, or use exposure compensation while using scene modes. You must use P, M, A or S modes to access these.  I can only assume the Coolpix would be similar.  Those scene modes are programmed for the camera to make all the decisions for you.